# How to log ids of document send by solr

Tags: solr, response

I have to log information about Solr response i.e. Solr by default provides logs of requests. I have to find which document is served and how many time it is served. How I can do it?

Comment: Write a `void logResult(TopDocs)` methods, increase ids by 1 in a table(id, count).

Comment: Can you elaborate. Where to write this method?

Comment: In my solr project, typically I would provide a search API base on the solr API, so that to hidden underling solr API for easy to use & security reason. In the wrapper API, typically for each core or collection, there will be a search method that return a `TopDocs` or `List<T>`. Write the `void logResult(TopDocs or List)`  method as a standard util, and call it in the search method of the wrapper API, pass the returned search result to the `logResult()` method, and design a db table to record that, you can also first use a map to cache the count in things like memcache then sync to db.

Comment: You should try solrJ for its implementation